# What is the proper sequence (right-left) for a kohen to follow when the Levi washes his hands before he duchens?

Tags: birchas-kohanim

There are two sequences used when we wash for sanctification: alternating: right-left three times (before davening, after leaving a cemetery) and non-alternating: right hand completely, left hand completely (before eating bread). Which one does a Kohen follow before reciting Birkat Kohanim?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Gary and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!